# Application has stopped, LOGIN

Tags: java, php, android, apache, authentication

everytime i press the Submit button on my login, it closes, i dont know what is the prob here..
..i am using XAMPP(MySql and Apache are both started)..
..i am using localhost/phpmyadmin
..my database is named "newdatabase"
..my table for login is named "mytable"
..inside "mytable" is [ss_num] and [passs] (these are correct(ss_num = username | passs = password))

public class Member_Log_In extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

```
 private EditText user, pass;

     private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

     JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
     private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.7/adrx/logins.php";
     private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
     private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";


     @Override

         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_member__log__in);

             user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
             pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
             mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLogin);

             mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);



         }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v==mSubmit){

        new loglogin().execute();

    }


    }


     class loglogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

          String username = user.getText().toString();

            String password = pass.getText().toString();


                @Override

                protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                    int success;


                    try {

                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ss_num", username));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passs", password));

                      JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                       // Log.d("request!", "starting");
                        Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                        if (success == 1) {


                            Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SUCCESS!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                        }else{


                            Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FAILED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                    return null;

                }
  }
                }
//end
```

---

ERRORLOG

```
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:205)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:119)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:324)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at com.example.citizenschartersss.Member_Log_In$loglogin.doInBackground(Member_Log_In.java:118)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at com.example.citizenschartersss.Member_Log_In$loglogin.doInBackground(Member_Log_In.java:1)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-18 22:10:36.133: E/AndroidRuntime(9954):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: Give us the error log, to see what's wrong faster.

Comment: did you given internet permission in manifiest file

Comment: yes, i have put internet permission..i also have the php file for the login, need help..
my email is adrian.vallinan.m4a1@outlook.com

Answer (score 0):

You cannot touch the UI in a background thread. For example, you cannot show `Toast`s in async task `doInBackground()`.

You can use `runOnUiThread()` to post a `Runnable` to the UI thread, or just change your debugging from toasts to regular logging.

Answer (score 0):

Toasts are UI and like all UI can only be manipulated on the main UI thread.

I would suggest using https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus (I'm not involved in this project, but have been using it for a while in production apps) to post the result of the login task and have your activity listen for those events on the UI thread, where you can modify the UI.